# Calling an API in background and reload the tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sockets

In my project I have to call an `API` to list the details in a `TableView`. As of now I am calling this `API` in a `dispatch_async` and reloading the `TableView` in `MainQueue`.

But the `UI` is stuck during the API call and user is not able to scroll it. Please find below the code. Please note that the API connection is done using `socket connection`, and I am using a 3rd party pod  for socket connection

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        ChatTitleLabel.text = chatTitleString

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

            self.fetchChatList(
        })
  }


 func fetchChatList() { 

    function for calling API (){

    //call back block

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    self.chatListTableView.reloadData()
                })
     }
}
```

Comment: i think you need to reload tableview in the completion handler function of API.

Comment: Hi @SumitDhariwal I am reloading it in completion block only

Comment: Check your third party api if they are using main queue.